# How to set PDF height dynamically using 'react-native-html-to-pdf' package?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, react-native

I am creating a PDF document in react-native. My aim is to create single page,no more pages and while my page's content gets bigger, my single page's height also must get bigger automatically.

```
options = {
            width: 675,
            height: ????,
            html: `<div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; min-height: 850px"> </div>`
            }
```

In the above code, I set myDiv's `min-height` and when myDiv's height changes dynamically, I want to take this height value and set the option's height automatically. I tried javascript `offsetHeight` property but it does not work because HTML's inside is completely a string. I tried to use template literals, but i couldn't succeed.

Is there a way to handle this,using template literals or any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can't be done with react-native-html-to-pdf.

If you read the package code, you'll find it does not include any option like that.

At least on android, you could try to measure the component yourself  [using the same tecnique they use to render html before printing it](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java), but it won't be an easy task: you will need to create a webview, inject the code, and extract the height of the desired component.

Try opening an issue on the github project, maybe they will add this feature on a future release.